# Rank changes with matrix edits

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, extremal-combinatorics

Assume we have rank $r$ real matrix $M\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ (not constrained to symmetric).

Assume $W\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ is rank $1$ real matrix.

**Case $1$**: $M+W\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$.

Could there be tight upper, lower bounds on $rank(M+W)-rank(M)$ depending on only $r$?

**Case $2$**: $M-W\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$.

Could there be tight upper, lower bounds on $rank(M-W)-rank(M)$ depending on only $r$?

---

Above can be reduced to rank $2$ matrices $W$ with symmetric cases.

Matrix $$0\mbox{ }M'$$$$M\mbox{ }0$$ is symmetric and has rank $2r$.

Matrix $$0\mbox{ }W'$$$$W\mbox{ }0$$ is symmetric and has rank $2$.

Comment: Btw, why the extremal-combinatorics tag? Is there an interesting application you have in mind?

Comment: Motivation comes from combinatorics. All 0-1 objects as far as I know have connections there.

Answer (score 2):

The interlacing theorem tells us that ***for rank 1 $W$*** the eigenvalues of $M \pm W$ are sandwiched between those of $M$ (see Corollary 4.3.9 [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=O7sgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=matrix%20analysis%20rank%20one%20interlacing&source=bl&ots=lUMbzifvi3&sig=jiUurTyRbBNn22_OtXniwllgnEk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YmrQVOzQB4KuUcvIgMgI&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=matrix%20analysis%20rank%20one%20interlacing&f=false)). Therefore
$null(M)-1 \leq nullity(M \pm W) \leq null(M)+1$ and this is equivalent to $r(M)-1 \leq r(M \pm W) \leq r(M)+1$.

These bounds are tight. For the case of graphs there are some detailed studies of when the different cases obtain.

Comment: @Turbo It's proved in the reference I gave (the standard one on the subject).

Comment: @Turbo The magic works because it's a rank 1 update. It's possible to use interlacing for rank $k$ updates, but the bounds get progressively weaker, of course. The proof for rank $k$ is just an inductive application of Corollary 4.3.9 $k$ times (decompose $W$ as the sum of $k$ matrices of rank $1$).

Comment: @Turbo Yes, all you need is Hermitianness of $M$ and $W$. But as I said, having $\{0,1\}$ helps to perhaps pinpoint precisely which of the three cases occurs.

Comment: @Turbo In that case, things are open again.... :( If you want to discuss the specific case, feel free to email me.

Comment: Problem reduces to rank $2$ in symmetric case.

Comment: So you say in this case $rank(M\pm W)\in[rank(M)-2,rank(M)+2]$?

Comment: @Turbo Yes, I think it does.

Comment: can you update your answer? So that I could close.

Answer (score 0):

There are similar interlacing theorems for singular values, so the bound is $\pm1$ even for the non-symmetric case. For a more elementary proof, $range(M+W) \subseteq range(M)+range(W)$, so comparing dimensions $rk(M+W)\leq rk(M) + 1$. Switching the roles of $M$ and $M+W$ yields the reverse inequality.